# Принцип написания условий в шаблонизаторе

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Доброго времени суток.
Хотелось бы узнать принцип написания условий в шаблонизаторе.

Шаблон примерно такого типа:

```
{{ if(1==2) }}
{{ else }}
{{ endif }}
```

Comment: Шаблон делится на блоки, условия парсятся, из них достаются условия и по ним создается или не создается тот или иной блок. Конкретно в твиге функциональные блоки достаются по тегам {% %}, насколько понимаю.

Comment: Мне бы примерный код. А лучше код нахождения условий. Так как дальше я понимаю как.

Comment: @Essle могу предложить скачать и посмотреть тот же Twig

Comment: Скачивал, но не нашел там нужный код.

Comment: могу предложить начать отсюда: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Parser.php#L63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала любой шаблон парсится в удобную для шаблонизатора структуру.

Как правило всё парсится в древовидну структуру.

`{{ if(1==2) }}
if content
{{ else }}
else content
{{ endif }}`

Этот кусок кода можно было бы отпарсить чтото вроде в:

`array(
    'block_type' => 'ifblock',
    'condition'  => '1==2',
    'content'    => 'if content',
    'else_content'=> 'else content',
)`

Ну и при прохождении по блокам смотреть тип, затем выполнять условие, если оно выполняется - отображать контент из content, если не выполняется то из else_content (если он есть, если нету - ничего не делаем)

Answer (score 1):

Берешь шаблон, разбиваешь его отдельно на куски html кода и отдельно на условия и т.п.
Дальше каждое условие парсишь, как тебе вздумается. Обычно вместо него подставляют реальный рабочий код языка. Дальше склеиваешь куски html кода и условий. Должно всё сойтись, если ты чего-нибудь из двух массивов не уберешь.